# How can I add two button (one is back, one is next) under scrollview that filled with textview and imageview in a screen, android?

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to ask, can I add next and back button under scrollview that filled with textview and imageview in one screen, both with it's xml, java and screenshot result for android?

Here's the picture I intend to ask.
I got from here: https://sensortower.com/android/nl/softartstudio/app/selfishop-camera/com.selfishop.camera/

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UT2o.png)

Where actually, what I really aim is a view like a blog (when you see an image on your above text that can be scrolled, where it's end with Back button that will go to previous page on the bottom left, and Next button that will go to the next page at the reverse side).

Really would like an example in xml, java, and it's screenshot result.

Again, thank you very much

Very appreciate your answer. Thank you

Comment: Stack Overflow is a question-and-answer site, not a coding service.  Please outline what you have tried and where exactly you are stuck.  Otherwise this question will be closed for being off-topic.

Comment: Thank you for reminding. Yes, I've already tried, and stuck. Thus that I ask here. Again, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what XML is for.

Create your layout in xml and import it via java.

You will want to create your own "bar layout" for the bars in the center, though you could I suppose, fill 3 separate LinearLayouts to achieve the same effect, making a separate layout and putting in it here will be easier for you to read, and follow along with what is happening.

Below is a mock up of the xml layout you would be using to get a view very similar to what you have in your picture. I have not tested this, this was made on the fly so it may not be perfect but it will get you very close to what you are looking for.

```
<LinearLayout>
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum=10
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout>
        android:weight=1
        android:layout_height=0dp
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
        <TextView>
            android:width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/info_bar"
            android:centerHorizontal="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout>
        android:weight=8
        android:width="match_parent"
        android:height=0dp>
        <TextView>
            android:id="@+id/text_view1"
            android:width="match_parent"
            android:height="wrap_content"/>
       <com.yourpackage.yourapp.createabarlayout>
       </com.yourpackage.yourapp.createabarlayout>
       <com.yourpackage.yourapp.createabarlayout>
       </com.yourpackage.yourapp.createabarlayout>
       <com.yourpackage.yourapp.createabarlayout>
       </com.yourpackage.yourapp.createabarlayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <RelativeLayout>
        android:weight=1
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height=0dp>
        <Button>
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/back_button"
            android:text="@string/back_button_hint"/>
        <TextView>
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/steps_textview"
            android:text="@string/steps_hint"
            android:centerHorizontal="true"/>
       <Button>
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/next_button"
            android:text="@string/next_button_hint"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you.

What is
<com.yourpackage.yourapp.createabarlayout>
       </com.yourpackage.yourapp.createabarlayout>
       <com.yourpackage.yourapp.createabarlayout>
       </com.yourpackage.yourapp.createabarlayout>
       <com.yourpackage.yourapp.createabarlayout>
       </com.yourpackage.yourapp.createabarlayout>

for?
Does it mean we have to change "yourpackagename.yourapp" with our own? and, 3 times?
Apologize for my unclear understanding.

Comment: That would be what I put in my answer yes. You will want to consider creating your own barlayout and including it in this, as, it will be easier for you to manage the xml, though again, you will be able to use most any layout you want to achieve the desired effect